# Communication between JS module and html (in fullduplex)

Tags: javascript, html, module, ecma

I've got an inline module script using other modules from a project.
I need to call module functions from html using onclick or everything else working..

```
<script type="module">
   import * as blabla from './somemodule.js';

   function myfunction(){
      console.log("Youhou!");
    }

   //Communication from script to html works fine
   document.getElementById('test').onclick = myfunction;
</script>
<button id="test">Test</button>
<button onclick="myfunction();">Test</button>//This dont work
```

Is this even possible ? Cant find anything on google and I'm a good googler.
Thank you very much !

Answer (score -1):

```
onClick="myFunction()"
```

or

```
jQuery('#clickable').click( myFunction() );
```

There is also VanillaJS solution for that...

```
getElementById('clickable').addEventListener('click', myFunction() )
```